# How Do I Change The Frame Of A ZBar Reader?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

Ok, so I'm using the ZBar SDK to scan barcodes in my iPhone app. I've successfully implemented the sample code, but now I want to change the frame of the scanner view (i.e: To half the screen size). I've tried setting the frame of the reader's view in viewDidLoad, but it resizes itself. 
I know this is going to be one of those really simple things I just missed, but any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

EDIT: I got it to work. Here's my code:

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
[reader setShowsZBarControls:NO];
[reader.readerView setScanCrop:(CGRect){ { 0, 0 }, { 0.43, 1 } }];
[reader.readerView start];
[self.view addSubview:reader.view];

overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[listTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 208, 320, 208)];
[overlayView addSubview:listTableView];
[self.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

Comment: I am working on barcode reader app which reads barcode and display its data using zbar Sdk. Now client wants to customize the square bracket which appears when camera auto focus the barcode. How to customize it like this??? http://i.stack.imgur.com/NkKQr.png Thanks

Comment: What does listTableView resolve to?  Is this a custom view you instantiated somewhere else?  Also is overlayView an iVar?

Comment: You are posting code which doesn't work. Can you please answer above comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out. This is what I had to do:

1. Add ZBarReaderViewController's view as subview of my own view (which annoyingly fills the entire view no matter what its frame is).
2. Change scan size of ZBarReaderViewController to whatever size I want it to be (BEWARE: Setting this frame is not like setting one normally, just ask if you need help).
3. Add any views that you want visible to the ZBarReaderViewController's overlay view.

This was very difficult and unintuitive and broke many of Apple's code design guidelines but, in the end, is still doable.

Comment: How did you reset the frame? Adding as a subview seems to provide a blank black screen.

Comment: Is your code similar to mine above? If not, try it and tell me how you go.

Comment: @Dyldo42 Can you put the Code Here?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using ZBarReaderViewController, try using ZBarReaderView. This worked for me and saved my lot of time. Hope it helps you.

```
ZBarReaderView*reader = [ZBarReaderView new];
ZBarImageScanner * scanner = [ZBarImageScanner new];
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
reader = [reader initWithImageScanner:scanner];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
reader.frame = CGRectMake(20, 38, 283, 347);
reader.torchMode = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{[reader start];});

[self.view addSubview:reader];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own view and view controller,and add the ZBarReaderViewController's view as a subview of your own view;

Comment: It's not as simple as that. See my answer above.

Comment: ZBarReaderViewController is a ViewController, not a UIView. So, you can't add simply as a subview!

Answer (score 0):

another way to modify the properties of the scanning view controller is to import the ZBarSDK project and compile and link it yourself, rather than using the binary version of the SDK. Then, you can make any changes to the view controller that you need to (keep in mind their license...should probably read that first)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
It may help you:

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader= [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
// TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

//    reader.showsCameraControls = NO;  // for UIImagePickerController
reader.showsZBarControls = NO;

// EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25|ZBAR_QRCODE
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
[reader viewDidLoad];
[reader viewWillAppear:NO];
[reader viewDidAppear:NO];

[self.viewScan addSubview:reader.view];
```

here,`self.viewScan` is any view of your current controller.

so scanning area now `self.viewScan` view.

Comment: But only one issue, barcode not scanner not detect and not called delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it so it will be inside a sampleView :

```
UIView *view = [self sampleView];
CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
[viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
[reader.view.layer setFrame:bounds];
[viewLayer insertSublayer:reader.view.layer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];
```